# OS X Lion VNC server alternative

Tags: macos, vnc

Since Lion, VNC seems to be hard to play with, is there any other VNC server alternative (except Vine Server which doesn't work at all on Lion)?

I also played with [iRapp](http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp) which is a RDP server and that worked so well but unfortunately it cost $80 so it's kind of expensive for the moderate usage I'd make out of it.

Any idea or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: IRapp is apparently in bankruptcy, since I upgrade OSX to Sierra my licensed copy no longer works.   This question _was_ providing me the exact information I was seeking.  Since the random 'off-topic' police closed this question, where do they suggest one DOES find this information when one needs it?   Somehow, I suspect the "not my problem" answer....

Comment: Vine Server doesn't work on lion? what about https://github.com/stweil/OSXvnc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative VNC Server could be [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/), an alternative to VNC itself could be [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) it works fine on Lion and it is free for moderate private use.

Comment: I need something to control a headless Mac on my LAN, and TeamViewer goes through the internets so it's too slow to be usable enough. As for RealVNC, only the Enterprise edition is working on Mac (As I read on their website). Thanks

Comment: Team Viewer can work also inside the local network...

Comment: For some reason it seems to be as slow as if I wasn't using it from the local network, I don't get why, I just investigate a bit more, thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry about arguing about what you said about TeamViewer, I just noticed a LAN option in the settings, and it works VERY well! Thanks!

Comment: RealVNC Free works fine on OS X: http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/licensing/

Answer (score 1):

My IT department restricts my access to the Screen Sharing part of Lion's preferences so I needed an alternative.  I was able to get RealVNC running as a server with a free license (phone and email required).  This was using 5.0.1 and Lion 10.7.4.  Very easy.

Answer (score 1):

A little late :) bu iRAPP for Lion now is free...

Comment: How is it free? On the web I see "Download the free 14-day trial".

Comment: It's free for Lion: http://www.coderebel.com/2013/11/14/irapp-for-osx-10-7-now-free

Answer (score 0):

For at least some uses (check the license), [Wyse PocketCloud](http://www.wyse.com/products/software/mobility/PocketCloud) may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually teamviewer 7.0.11067 have a bug which provide to black screen view when you connect to your mac when it were in Economy Power mode... and it is sad.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a *comment, not an answer*  to the question. With sufficient [**reputation**](http://superuser.com/faq#reputation), you can use the "add comment" button to leave feedback for the author.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/

Though oddly named, this VNC program, "Chicken of the VNC", works great, I just tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Lion's built in VNC server works just fine, they just changed the authentication process and many clients are no-longer capable of logging on, especially ones that haven't been updated since Lion came out or where Mac compatibility is a low priority.

In my experience, the ones that haven't been updated for Lion support by now usually didn't work very well with OS X anyway (poor system integration).

These days there are plenty of Lion compatible VNC clients available. I use it all the time with an iPad app I found, and it works great.

Comment: Okay, if there's so many of them which are working, why don't you state some of them? Thanks

Comment: The one I bought works: Remotix. Apple's own Screen Sharing (free for home/small business use) and Apple Remote Desktop (expensive/for enterprise) obviously both work. Six or seven other free/cheap iOS apps I tried before settling on Remotix all worked. I only ever run Windows in a virtual machine, so I haven't tested any there. I didn't find any app that doesn't work, though they all did have a "mac" authentication type. My understanding is VNC is a loose standard, that doesn't really define an authentication protocol. These days Apple has one that's a bit different from windows.

Comment: Oh, I was searching one that works with a VNC windows client, and the only one that says that it works is RealVNC which unfortunately gives a mediocre performance :-/ But thanks